# Examine the end behavior of $f(x)$ and find any horizontal asymptotes.

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x)=\frac{10x^3-3x^2+8}{\sqrt{25x^6+x^4+2}}$
and this is what I have done so far

I divided the numerator and denominator by $x^6$,

$f(x)=\frac{\frac{10x^3-3x^2+8}{x^6}}{\frac{\sqrt{25x^6+x^4+2}}{x^6}}$=
$\frac{\frac{10}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^4}+\frac{8}{x^6}}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{x^{6}}+\frac{1}{x^{8}}+\frac{2}{x^{12}}}}$

This is about where I got stuck(with the denominator)

Comment: Fixed a mistake I made:  $x^6 \neq \sqrt{x^{36}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you a trick that can be used for complicated limits like this. Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{(A x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n)^k}{(Bx^m + b_1x^{m-1} + \cdots + b_m)^j}
\end{align}
Where $A$ and $B$ are the leading terms.
What is the limit of this function as $x$ approaches infinity? Recall that when evaluating limits that are a ratio of polynomials, you take the ratios of the leading terms(assuming they are the same degree). The problem is in this case is that the numerator and denominator are not in their standard form. How can we solve this? Well remember we only care about the largest term. If $j$ and $k$ are positive and $n$ and $m$ are positive then the largest term will be the first. These largest terms will clearly be $A^kx^{nk}$ and $B^jx^{mj}$. This means 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{A^kx^{nk}}{B^jx^{mj}} 
\end{equation}
Remember the limit is finite iff the exponents of $x$ are the same, so $nk = mj$. In your example you can see that $3(1) = 6(\frac{1}{2})$ so this limit is correct. This means that the limit is just
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \frac{A^k}{B^j}
\end{equation}
Or in your example $\frac{10^1}{25^\frac{1}{2}} = 2$. If you remember this trick, you can solve all of these problems pretty much instantly. Now if you want to do it the long way (like for a test maybe) then try factoring
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} &= \frac{10x^3-3x^2 + 8}{(25x^6 + x^4 + 2)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{10x^3 - 3x^2 + 8}{((25x^6)(1 + \frac{1}{25x^2} + \frac{2}{25x^6}))^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{10x^3 - 3x^2 + 8}{5x^3(1 + \frac{1}{25x^2} + \frac{2}{25x^6})^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{10 - \frac{3}{x} + \frac{8}{x^3}}{5(1 + \frac{1}{25x^2} + \frac{2}{25x^6})^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{10 - 0}{5(1 + 0)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= 2
\end{align}

Comment: ok that makes sense! when you factored the problem, how did you get 25x^6 down to 5x^3?

Comment: @user289643 You are taking it out of the square root since $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{25x^6} = 5x^3$

Comment: @ Jeevan Devaranjan  Thank you! (this is here just so it is more than 15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

I redid the problem from scratch (thanks to $\ Jeevan\,Devaranjan$ ) and here's my work:
$\frac{10x^3-3x^2+8}{\sqrt{25x^6+x^4+2}} \\ \; \; \; \; \; \; = \\ \frac{\frac{10x^3}{x^3}-\frac{3x^2}{x^3}\frac{+8}{x^3}}{\sqrt{\frac{25x^6}{x^6}+\frac{x^4}{x^6}+\frac{2}{x^6}}}\\ \; \; \; \; \; \; = \\ \frac{{10}-\frac{3}{x}\frac{+8}{x^3}}{\sqrt{25+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^6}}} \\ \; \; \; \; \; \; = \\ \color{blue}{\mathsf{Apply\,Infinity\,Properties}} \\  \frac{{10}-0+0}{\sqrt{25+0+0}} \\ \; \; \; \; \; \; = \\ \;\, \frac{10}{5}=2 \\ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{10x^3-3x^2+8}{\sqrt{25x^6+x^4+2}}=\color{red}2$